# Symfony2 Dynamic Generation for Forms, form submit throwing PRE_SET_DATA error

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, event-listener

I am attempting to create a dynamic form, much like Symfony's example [of dynamic form modification](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms)

I have a parent form Type of "AttributeType" which contains a collection of "AttributeDetailTypes". The child AttributeDetailType() form is where I have my listeners set up:

```
$attributeDetailFields = $options['attributeDetailFields'];
    $builder
        ->add('attributeDetailField', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'RelayRiseBundle:AttributeDetailField',
            'choices' => $attributeDetailFields,
            'property' => 'name'
        ));
```

My listeners will populate a field 'value' with a field type based on the user's selected 'attributeDetailField':

```
  $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, AttributeDetailField $attributeDetailField = null) {
        print($attributeDetailField->getName());
        if($attributeDetailField->getDataType()->getValue() === 'date') {
            $form->add('value', 'collot_datetime', array('pickerOptions' =>
                array("format" => "mm/dd/yyyy",
                    "todayBtn" => "linked",
                    "autoclose" => true,
                    "minView" => "month",
                    "todayHighlight" => true),
            ));
        } else {
            $form->add('value', 'text');
        }
  }
```

So I have PRE_SET_DATA and POST_SUBMIT event listeners.

```
    $builder->addEventListener(
         FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
         function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {

            if (null != $event->getData()) {
                $data = $event->getData();
                $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getAttributeDetailField());
            }
        }
    );

  $builder->get('attributeDetailField')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            if (null != $event->getData()) {
                $attributeDetailField = $event->getForm()->getData();
                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $attributeDetailField);
            }

        }
    );
```

The PRE_FORM_DATA listener works great when the form is populated. The problem is when I do my AJAX callback to the controller which triggers a form->submit. Then the POST_SUBMIT listener AND the PRE_FORM_DATA listener are called, and I get the following error:

"A cycle was detected. Listeners to the PRE_SET_DATA event must not call setData(). You should call setData() on the FormEvent object instead"

How can I submit my form via Ajax, trigger my POST_SUBMIT listener without throwing the PRE_SET_DATA error?

Comment: I'm suddenly running into this issue as well, working code is suddenly not working without having been changed. DId you manage to find a fix for this?

Comment: Same issue for me.. `ParentType` has a Collection Field of `ChildType`. `ChildType` is composed of two fields `existingElements` and `quantity`. I want that  list of `existingElements` depends on user's choice (ajax call & co). 
I am now stuck with this.. Did you find a solution ?